# Describing a group of mismatched characters

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to remember the description that is often used to portray a group of characters that wouldn't quite belong together under normal circumstances, something analogous to a dysfunctional family. It's not a metaphor to the best of my knowledge, but it is quite common in film summaries.

Also, I've often seen it used as a description for the group of races that constitute the Horde (in the Warcraft universe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An incongruous group of characters is a **motley crew**.

Comment: Motley crew isn't exactly what I was looking for, but your answer did lead me to find the term. It's **[ragtag bunch of misfits](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RagtagBunchOfMisfits)**.